# EXCEL VBA: How to fix Pivot Table error when attempting to use UsedRange?

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I am trying to create a simple pivot table with Gas on the column, Dash No. for the row, and my Qty for the input. 
I've been researching this question and cannot find a solution. When I try to run my code I keep getting

> Error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error.

Here is my code:

```
Sub CreatePivotTable()

Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = Worksheets("mac3")

Sheets.Add.Name = "Table"
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
sheet.UsedRange, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14). _
CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Table!R3C1", TableName:="Pvt" _
, DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14

    Sheets("Table").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pvt").PivotFields("Gas")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pvt").PivotFields("Dash")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pvt").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "Pvt").PivotFields("Qty"), "Sum of Qty", xlSum
    Range("B4").Select
    Selection.Group Start:=True, End:=True, Periods:=Array(False, False, False, _
        False, True, False, False)
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line of code is throwing that error?

Comment: @ojf I've located the issue! `ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
sheet.UsedRange, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14). _
CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Table!R3C1", TableName:="Pvt" _
, DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14` Theres something wrong with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you already have  a "Pvt" in your Worksheet?
It can cause this error, in that case you can try changing the sheet and table names to something else